# editablegrid set columns for rendering a bar chart graph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, editablegrid

I'm using [editableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net) for my project and I want to create a graph, with values from only 1 column.

When using [`renderBarChart()` function](http://www.editablegrid.net/documentation/symbols/EditableGrid.html#renderBarChart), the table renders a graph, but with all numeric columns (set in metadata as integer or double) as data. So I have graph with data which are not related at all. Is there a way, how to force the graph to load data from 1 column (eg. only price)?

Comment: show you table and use of renderBarChart call

Comment: @ProstoTrader i set columns in metadata part with `bar: false` attribute and now it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Only thing you have to do is set columns in metadata part with attribute `bar: false` in order to remove those columns from rendering in graphs.

```
editableGrid.load({ metadata: [
    { name: "price",      label:"Price",      datatype: "double(CZK,2)",   editable: true, },
    { name: "discount",   label:"Dis.",       datatype: "double(CZK,2)",   editable: true,    bar: false },
    { name: "count",      label:"Pieces",     datatype: "integer",         editable: true,    bar: false }
]});
```

This is not IMHO the best way to do this. This way if you want to have 2 separate graphs (eg. price of product and number on stock), you can't do it, because you have stock count set not to show in graphs.

Much nicer would be to modify the function, and pass into arguments array of columns, which you want to display, like so:

```
editableGrid.renderCharts = function() {
    this.renderBarChart("chart-graph", 'Prices', 'product_name', ['price_amount', 'discount'], {alpha: 0.75, bar3d: false});
};
```

Just saying, if any developer is looking